# I don't understand how this user array is sorted using sort function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

there is an array called users which has objects with in there is personal information of different persons.
there is a function called getDatesfromString which strips string to date format.
there is a variable called sorted_user which is meant to contain the sorted user array.
the thing i don't understand is that how sort function sorts the user by getting their Date of birth , I need detail explanation?

```js
let users = [
    {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "wick",
        email:"johnwick@gamil.com",
        DOB:"22-01-1990",
    },
    {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "smith",
        email:"johnsmith@gamil.com",
        DOB:"21-07-1983",
    },
    {
        firstName: "Joyal",
        lastName: "white",
        email:"joyalwhite@gamil.com",
        DOB:"21-03-1989",
    },
];

function getDateFromString(strDate) {
    let [dd,mm,yyyy] = strDate.split('-')
    return new Date(yyyy+"/"+mm+"/"+dd);
}
    
// console.log(sorted_users);
    let sorted_users=users.sort(function(a, b) {
        let d1 = getDateFromString(a.DOB);
        let d2 = getDateFromString(b.DOB);
            return d1-d2;
          });
    console.log(sorted_users);
```

Comment: Date's are internally stored as a `number` (the number of milliseconds since `1 Jan 1970 00:00 UTC` to be precise) ... so it's just like sorting numbers

Comment: by the way, `getDateFromString` could simply `return +\`${yyyy}${mm}${dd}\`;` and you'd still be able to sort correctly

Comment: or even better, the whole function could be a single statement `return strDate.split('-').map(v => v.padStart(2, "0")).reverse().join("")` - maybe that will be easier to understand

Comment: @JaromandaX it probably should be `return new Date(yyyy, mm, dd);` instead of `new Date(yyyy+"/"+mm+"/"+dd)`, but still that code is totally fine and handles dates with variable numbers of digits per part, unlike your suggestions

Comment: sure, it does @Bergi, I get that, but then technically it should be `return new Date(yyyy, mm - 1, dd);` - but my second suggestion fixes variable number of digits anyway

Comment: @JaromandaX oops, indeed! But your second suggestion still does not deal with years with an arbitrary number of digits

Comment: well, since the year comes first, does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.sort` accepts a callback function with 2 parameters, essentially what it does is it will determine in which order you want the `a` and `b` will be after sorted.

In this case it calls inside the `sort` function `getDateFromString` to get the `Number` value of the date of both `a` and `b` and then it does `return d1-d2` which means:

- if `d2` is bigger than `d1`, it will return negative number and will put `d2` after `d1`, which resulting ascending sort.

| compareFn(a, b) return value | sort order |
| --- | --- |
| > 0 | sort a after b, e.g. [b, a] |
| < 0 | sort a before b, e.g. [a, b] |
| === 0 | keep original order of a and b |

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

While you got the answer please note that you don't need to convert `DOB` into `Date` since you can compare strings immediately as numbers. That would be 9x faster:

1. DOB.slice(-4) - you got the year part
2. DOB.slice(3,2) - you got the month part
3. DOB.slice(0,2) - you got the day part

```
` Chrome/120
----------------------------------------------------------------
Alexander            1.00x  |  x1000000  119  122  125  128  129
original             9.66x  |   x100000  115  115  115  115  116
----------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
let users = [
    {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "wick",
        email:"johnwick@gamil.com",
        DOB:"22-01-1990",
    },
    {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "smith",
        email:"johnsmith@gamil.com",
        DOB:"21-07-1983",
    },
    {
        firstName: "Joyal",
        lastName: "white",
        email:"joyalwhite@gamil.com",
        DOB:"21-03-1989",
    },
];

// @benchmark original

users.sort(function(a, b) {
            let d1 = getDateFromString(a.DOB);
            let d2 = getDateFromString(b.DOB);
                return d1-d2;
              });

function getDateFromString(strDate) {
    let [dd,mm,yyyy] = strDate.split('-')
    return new Date(yyyy+"/"+mm+"/"+dd);
}


// @benchmark Alexander

users.sort(({DOB:a}, {DOB:b}) => a.slice(-4) - b.slice(-4) || a.slice(3,2) - b.slice(3,2) || a.slice(0,2) - b.slice(0,2));

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Answer (score -1):

The `sort` function is organizing the `users` array based on their dates of birth (`DOB`). Here's a detail Explaination:

1. **Comparison Function:**

   - The `sort` function compares two users at a time using a function.
   - This function converts the birthdate strings to date objects for accurate comparison.
2. **Date Comparison:**

   - For each pair of users, it subtracts one birthdate from the other.
   - If the result is negative, it means the first user is born earlier.
   - If positive, the first user is born later.
   - If zero, their order remains unchanged.
3. **Sorting:**

   - The `sort` function rearranges the users based on the comparison results.
   - After sorting, the array is in ascending order of birthdates.